# Xcode8 Swift3 ImageURL returns nil

Tags: image, url, download, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to download an image from my web server, using Xcode 8 and  Swift 3.  It looks like this.  The request returns nil.  Any suggestions why?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var view1: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

@IBAction func load(_ sender: UIButton) {

  let url = URL(string:"http://www.example.com/folder2/pic3-1.jpg")

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, 
error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

        DispatchQueue.main.sync() {
            self.view1.image = UIImage(data: data)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
    }

@IBAction func reset(_ sender: UIButton) {

    self.view1.image="blankU.png"

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
```

Any idea why the image is returning nil from the server?

Comment: Why don't you ask the `error` parameter of `dataTask`?

Comment: Can the error parameter be printed to the debugging window with print(error) ?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: print(error) displays: nil.  Is there something wrong with the web server?  The photo is there according to the ftp manager.  But it doesn't respond to a call from Safari either.

Comment: You should use dispatch **async** (without parentheses) `DispatchQueue.main.async {... `

Comment: Both sync() and async work with let url = URL(string:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6a/Johann_Sebastian_Bach.jpg").  But neither works with the image in my web directory.  Also the Bach.jpg responds to a call from safari.

Comment: Then there might be something wrong with the image itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xcode8, Swift3 coding is okay.  The server is blocked.